# "SCT Device Updater" in Wine crashes whenever I use some of its functions or try and reinstall, repair, or remove software

Tags: wine

I have a car tuner updater software called SCT Device Updater, that I am trying to run in Wine.  When I try and use it's function to upload custom tunes to the car tuner, it crashes.  It also crashes when I try and use the installer to modify, remove, or repair the program.  Each time it crashes with an error of "msiexec.exe has encountered a serious problem".

I only just installed Ubuntu.  What can I do to make this software work under Wine on Ubuntu?

Comment: `msiexec.exe` suggests this is a Windows program.  Windows executables do not work under Ubuntu without Wine, and many WIndows softwares do not operate under Wine.  Are you using Wine, or Windows, when you gte these errors?

Comment: I was using wine to open the tuner software. lol at how i was negged

Comment: To update the firmware of external devices the updater program needs direct access to the communication link to the device, which is not available for USB from within Wine.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any details on the software on the Wine AppDB.

However, it is quite likely that this software does not correctly function under Wine, and relies on (like many proprietary software pieces) a full Windows installation, and not just an emulation layer, to make it work with all the functions.  You state that it crashes when you try and use some of its functions, which supports this, as it "starts" and "runs" but it's not really usable.  There is a lot of software that has this type of issue under Wine.

I can only suggest the following:

1. **Run Wine in Windows XP Emulation Mode**

   Run `winecfg`, and choose "Windows XP" for the Windows Version, and hit "OK".
2. If that doesn't work, **select the earliest Windows Version in that drop down that the software is reported to work on** in `winecfg` and try again.
3. If neither of these steps work, then you are very likely not going to get the software to work properly under Wine.  This is, unfortunately, quite commonplace with many many proprietary applications.

There is, unfortunately, no guarantee that all apps work under wine, and it's possible this is the case with this piece of software - it may just not work under Wine / Ubuntu.

Comment: Well that sucks, still wont work, I tried XP, 10, and 2008. Nothing. Its not that big of a deal, i'll just download the tunes from a friends computer. But it'd be nice to get that working.